# Create trigger function(e) programmatically Google Script (one single Sheet )

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a trigger instable 
`function solve(e) { ..}` and I want to have it programmatically because now I have to set the trigger manually.I've did a function and deleted the solve trigger before:

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('solve')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

I've only written this code and it's not enough because now I don't have any solve function modification it's because of the parameter e or it's another trick my spreadsheet has only one sheet ? Thank you very much.

Comment: I've put the code the trigger doesn't work like it worked when it was manually and I have to specify that I've deleted the old one solve(e)

Comment: Thank you for you answer i will try to explain I've only deleted the trigger solve (that works when I edit the Spreadsheet) I've set before ; the function solve is still in the code with createSpreadsheetEditTrigger function so I have these 2 function (now when I edit in the Spreadsheet I don't have a change in the code and my question is there is something I have still have to set?

Comment: Thank you very much I works it's true I haven't run the createSpreadsheetEditTrigger function to create the trigger now I get it better how it works :) ^^ you saved my life because in my case it's a container bound script so if I share the spreadsheet to a different user he will inherit the trigger or he has to set it manually?

Comment: So you mean share the spreadsheet and have createSpreadsheetEditTrigger2() function and run it (on the user account) to set the trigger for him and by doing this me and the user we will be able to edit in the same time without conflict data

Comment: Thank you very much I've tried to do this the fact is that my script when I edit in a cell it changes a Google Doc text that is related to this cell so with another user when he is the only active user in the sheet it works(I am not in the sheet) but when we are both even on different ranges of cells if he edits it will write 2 times the same thing in the Google Doc we have in another folder

Comment: Look into Lockservice https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much @I'-'I so the problem is solved :)  I forgot to run the createSpreadsheetEditTrigger function in order to create the solve trigger